# UIGravityBehavior Action in Swift

Tags: swift, uikit-dynamics

I am currently implementing a UIGravityBehavior to move a menu from the bottom to the screen that stops at the top and when pressing the button again I want it to move back and disappear at the bottom.

```
var gravity : UIGravityBehavior = UIGravityBehavior(items: [testView])
gravity.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(0.0, -0.6)
collision.addBoundaryWithIdentifier("TopEdge", fromPoint: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.origin, toPoint: CGPointMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.maxX, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.minY))
animator.addBehavior(collision)
animator.addBehavior(gravity)
```

when menu is shown and the button is pressed again I do the following

```
var gravity : UIGravityBehavior = UIGravityBehavior(items: [testView])
gravity.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.6)
animator.addBehavior(gravity)
```

I've tried the following

```
animator.action({ 
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(CGRectMake(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.maxY + self.testView.frame.size.height + 40, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.maxX, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.maxY), self.testView.frame)) {
                println("Stopped")
            }
})
```

but I get the following error Cannot convert the expression's type '$T4' to type '@lvalue (() -> Void)!'

Also tried to set a collisioin boundary outside of the screen but apparently it doesn't work either.

Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: What's the last statement in "code that checks when it leaves the screen"? If you have a closure that's expected to return `Void`, and the last line in the closure has a value, that value is inferred as an implicit `return` statement, leading to errors like the one you describe.

Comment: just checked what you said even tried with a func that is Void and just executes a println("Test") and still fails. The func is called with the gravity.action(testFunc())